# In how many ways can the assignment be made if the preferences are to be satisfied.

Tags: combinatorics

A firm of Chartered Accountants in London has to send $10$ clerks to $5$ different companies,two clerks in each.Two of the companies are in London and the others are outside.Two of the clerks prefer to work in London while the three others prefer to work outside.In how many ways can the assignment be made if the preferences are to be satisfied.

---

As two clerks prefer to work in London and three clerks prefer to work outside.
For London we need to select $2$ more clerks as there are $2$ companies in London.
For outside we need to select $3$ more clerks as there are $3$ companies outside London.
We need to make two groups,one of size $2$ clerks(for London) and one of size $3$ clerks(for outside London).This can be done in $\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$ ways.
But the answer given is $5400.$I dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: Suppose the companies are A,B,X,Y,Z with A,B in London. Sending clerks 1 and 2 to A and 3 and 4 to B is considered different from sending 1 and 3 to A and 2 and 4 to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider cases.

**Case 1:**  The two clerks who express a preference for London are sent to the same firm in London and the three clerks who wish to work outside London are sent to different firms outside London.

There are two ways of assigning the clerks who express a preference for working in London to the same firm.  Two of the five clerks who do not express a location preference are assigned to the other firm in London.  There are $3!$ ways of assigning the three clerks who express a preference for working outside London to different firms.  There are also $3!$ ways of assigning the remaining three clerks to different firms.
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{2} \cdot 3! \cdot 3!$$

**Case 2:**  The two clerks who express a preference for London are sent to the same firm in London and two of the three clerks who wish to work outside London are sent to the same firm outside London while the other clerk who wishes to work outside London is sent to a different firm outside of London.

There are two ways of assigning the clerks who express a preference for working in London to the same firm.  Two of the five clerks who do not express a location preference are assigned to the other firm in London.  There are three ways of selecting the firm outside to which two of the three clerks who express a preference for working outside London will be assigned and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of selecting which two of those three clerks will be assigned there.  There are then two choices for assigning the other clerk who wishes to work outside London to one of the two remaining firms outside London.  There are three choices for the other person who works at that firm and one way of assigning the remaining two clerks to the third firm outside London. 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$

**Case 3:**  The two clerks who express a preference for London are sent to different firms in London and the three clerks who wish to work outside London are sent to different firms outside London.

There are $2!$ ways of assigning the clerks who express a preference for London to different firms in London.  There are $3!$ ways of assigning the clerks who express a preference for working outside of London to different firms outside London.  There are $5!$ ways of assigning the remaining clerks to different firms.
$$2! \cdot 3! \cdot 5!$$

**Case 4:**  The two clerks who express a preference for London are sent to different firms in London and two of the three clerks who wish to work outside London are sent to the same firm outside London while the other clerk who wishes to work outside London is sent to a different firm outside of London.

There are $2!$ ways of assigning the clerks who express a preference for London to different firms in London.  There are five ways to assign a clerk who does not express a location preference to the firm in London whose name appears first on an alphabetical list and four ways of assigning a clerk who does not express a location preference to the other firm in London.  There are three ways of selecting the firm outside to which two of the three clerks who express a preference for working outside London will be assigned and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of selecting which two of those three clerks will be assigned there.  There are then two choices for assigning the other clerk who wishes to work outside London to one of the two remaining firms outside London.  There are three choices for the other person who works at that firm and one way of assigning the remaining two clerks to the third firm outside London. 
$$2! \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$

Since the four cases are mutually exclusive, the number of ways of assigning the clerks can be found by adding the totals for the four cases.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call 1 and 2 the clerks wishing to work in London and 3, 4 and 5 the clerks wishing to work outside London.  We can get an assignment of the clerks to the companies by arranging the 10 clerks in order and then pairing them up in order, so that the ith pair is assigned to company i.

1) There are $\dbinom{5}{2}=10$ ways to choose 2 other clerks to work in London.

2) There are $\displaystyle\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$ ways to assign the 4 London clerks to their companies.

3) There are $\displaystyle\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}=90$ ways to assign the 6 other clerks to their companies.

This give $10\cdot6\cdot90=\color{blue}{5400}$ possibilities.